# How to use try-catch to catch the segmentation error of an external code?

Tags: matlab, try-catch

I am calling an external exec. file (not written by me) using the `system()` command inside the MATLAB code. For some reasons the external file s/t gives the Segmentation fault error, and if I run the code again, it gets fixed.

Therefore, as we do in other languages, I am using `try` `catch` to catch the error, w/o stopping the whole process. Here is what I have written:

```
flag = false;
while(~flag)
    try
        system('….');
        flag = true;
    catch MExc
        flag = false;
    end
end
```

However, it does not catch the error. How to fix it?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Have you seen the [***examples***](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html#bujy28i-3) in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can catch an exception thrown by an external application when called within Matlab (actually it's not a doubt, I'm certain, but the sentence is much more elegant). Anyway, from my knowledge, an application that shuts down without errors should return an `ExitCode` equal to `0`.

Fortunately, the `system` function returns that value as its first output argument ([official documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html)), so try the following code instead:

```
status = -1;

while (status ~= 0)
    [status,cmdout] = system('...');
end

% do something with cmdout
```